# Summation of OMNI work items and Non OMNI work items (Open tabs)

Tags: omnichannel

Hello Salesforce Experts,

I have requirement that, We need the Count of Tabs(Service Requests) were opened, When the Salesforce Omnichannel assigned service requests and not assigned by Omnichannel.

Ultimately what we need is we need to calculate the Service request agent capability, Like how many Opened Service request does he has? both Omnichannel and Non-Omnichannel assigned Tasks?

Help will really appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Thanks,
Satish.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use Agent Work object to query records which are assign using omnichannel.

When omnichannel assign records to agent then it creates a entry in Agent Work.

1. If it pushed into omnichannel to agent and it opens a tab in console the agent work status will be opened.
2. If tab is closed then agent work status will become closed.

You can play around with agent work object to check what happens when a record is assigned to agent using omnichannel.

Thanks,
Manish Porwal